# how to add an 'all' option on a dropdown?

Tags: javascript, typescript, drop-down-menu, angular7, dropdown

I have a dropdown component that filters a list according to a 'state' data. 
here's my dropdown html:

```
<section class="select-wrapper {{wrapperClass}}" [ngClass]="{'expanded': toggle}" (click)="toggleSelect($event)">
    <input 
    type="text" 
    [hidden]="true"
    disabled="true"
    />  
    <div class="data-display" [ngClass]="{'has-value': title}">{{title}}</div>
    <label>
        <span>
          {{label}}
        </span>
      </label>
      <div class="search-wrapper" *ngIf="search && toggle && !disabled">
        <input
        class="search"
        type="text"
        autofocus
        (input)="changeSearch($event.target.value)"
        />
      </div>    
  <ul *ngIf="toggle && !disabled">
    <li *ngFor='let opt of options' (click)="clickAction(opt)" [hidden]="opt.show === false"> {{opt.title}}</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

here's how is called in my html component:

```
          <ciev-select-dropdown *ngIf="orders_states.length > 1" wrapperClass="custom-input-mid" label="Filter by state" (eClickAction)="this.setStateSelected($event)" [options]="orders_states"></ciev-select-dropdown>
```

here's my orders component ts:

```
  setStateSelected(singleStates: any) {
    singleStates = singleStates;
    this.stateSelected.emit(singleStates);
    if (singleStates !== undefined && singleStates !== null) {
      this.orders.forEach((item: { disabled: boolean; marking: any; }) => {
        item.disabled = item.marking !== singleStates;
      });
    if (singleStates === 'all') {
      this.orders.forEach((item: { disabled: boolean; marking: any; }) => {
        item.disabled = item.marking === singleStates;
      });
    }
    }
  }

  setStateOptions(orders: { marking: any; }) {

    const exist = this.orders_states.find((e: { value: any; }) => e.value === orders.marking);
    if (exist === undefined) {
      let title = '';
      switch (orders.marking) {
        case 'draft': title = 'Unfinished order' ;
        break;
        case 'pending': title = 'Pending confirmation';
        break;
        case 'validated': title = 'Order confirmed';
        break;
      }

      this.options_states.push(
        { title: title , value: orders.marking},
      );
    }
  }
```

I would like to include a fourth option that encompasses all the other states, so that I can show the complete list again. I`ve tried this:

```
switch (convention.marking) {
        case 'all': title = 'All your orders';
        break;
        case 'draft': title = 'Unfinished order' ;
        break;
        case 'pending': title = 'Pending confirmation';
        break;
        case 'validated': title = 'Order confirmed';
        break;
      }
      this.options_states.push(
        { title: title , value: convention.marking}        
      );
}
```

and this:

```
      this.options_states.push(
        { title: title , value: convention.marking},
        { title: 'All your orders' , value 'all'}
      );
```

but in both cases I created one more option for each of the originals, being a total of six search options but none of them has the complete list.

Any help is welcome. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve found the solution.

I don't know if it's a correct solution. In the ngOnInit of the ts component where I use my dropdown component I added the

```
this.options_states.push(
        { title: 'All your orders' , value 'all'}
      );
```

and this returns an array with the four values and allows me to select an 'all' option to display all my orders again. 
Thank you all for your attention